# Trino query failing with local memory exceeded exception

Tags: sql, trino

I was facing this error for a query:

> io.trino.ExceededMemoryLimitException: Query exceeded per-node memory
> limit of 75GB [Allocated: 74.94GB, Delta: 119.17MB, Top Consumers:
> {TableScanOperator=74.78GB, TopNProcessor=167.73MB,
> TaskOutputOperator=56.49MB}]

I have set 75Gb max memory per node, headroom memory 15GB and 1TB total max memory but I also enabled spilling with 100GB per query. I was hoping that spilling will keep this query running even though it goes beyond 75GB. Is my understanding correct or am i missing something?

thanks